# Solid bodies and parenting

Tags: parent, rigidbody

I have created a pseudo-cube that can be inverted--with parenting and rotations--to display a surprising inside.

I also would like to make the cube interact with a plane it falls on.

I can see that when I try to make the sides of the cube Rigid Bodies, I get the following message for some of them: "Rigid Body can't be child of a non compound Rigid Body."

And the animation does not work so good from then on. How can I fix that?

See blend file if needed...
[image]

Comment: maybe read the answer here: https://blenderartists.org/t/what-does-this-mean-rigid-body-cant-be-child-of-a-non-compound-rigid-body/1328737/5

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

[image]

Either you make your parent a compound rigid body or you unparent your other rigid bodies.